# In React-Native, how can I call popToTop() for each NavigatorIOS tab within TabBarIOS?

Tags: react-native, tabbarios

The app I am building has a root client object that affects all of the subsequent views of the app. I want the user to be able to change clients and have all of the tabs reset, i.e. `popToTop()` and update the client appropriately.

I have a `TabBarIOS` component with 4 tabs, each tab is a `NavigatorIOS` component that manages the subsequent `ListView` components. How can I force all the NavigatorIOS components to `popToTop()` and re-render based on a client change?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach would be to use an event emitter. Create an event emitter and pass it down to the component that owns the `NavigatorIOS` components. The owner can use the `ref` prop of each `NavigatorIOS` component to get a reference to each navigator.

The owner then can add a listener to the event emitter, and call `popToTop()` on each navigator when the listener is invoked. Then, it's just a matter of emitting the event when appropriate.

Comment: I will give it a go, thanks. Having never used Event Emitters, is there some code I can look at?

Comment: Sure, they are super common in JavaScript: https://nodejs.org/api/events.html https://github.com/facebook/emitter

Comment: Thanks, the emitter did work. I was still having trouble with NavigatorIOS screens updating with props change though. I think I will have to bite the bullet and start using NavigationExperimental...EventEmitter will still come in handy though!